# DirectMusic, including <dmusici.h>

Tags: c++, directx, directmusic

The problem is:
When I include `<dmusici.h>`, I get following errors:

```
dmdls.h:81: error: declaration of `WLOOP _DMUS_REGION::WLOOP[1]'
dls1.h:264: error: changes meaning of `WLOOP' from `typedef struct _rloop WLOOP'
```

An example:

```
using namespace std;

#include <d3d9.h>
#include <dmusici.h>

int main()
{
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but what is this? What IDE are you using? If I had to take a guess I would say there's probably something wrong with your include directories, or you're missing some SDK. There's really no way that someone will be able to help you unless you provide some more information.

Comment: DirectMusic? Wasn't that removed from the DirectX SDK back in 2007?

Answer (score 0):

The errors you get mean you can only include one of those libraries, because some `<dmusici.h>` declarations overlaps on declarations done in `<d3d9.h>`.

So only one of those can be included to your project.